# Wordpress REST API user registration

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to create new user with api v2 but i am getting

`{
    "code": "rest_cannot_create_user",
    "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to create new users.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}`

as I understand this is due to not sending **Nonce** headers with the request. But i can't figure out how to get Nonce id.

Answer (score 3):

If really you don't care about who can create an account you can:

go ->
wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-users-controller.php

find ->

```
public function create_item_permissions_check( $request ) {

if ( ! current_user_can( 'create_users' ) ) {
    return new WP_Error(
        'rest_cannot_create_user',
        __( 'Sorry, you are not allowed to create new users.' ),
        array( 'status' => rest_authorization_required_code() )
    );
}
```

and just replace the code to always return true ->

```
public function create_item_permissions_check( $request ) {

if ( ! current_user_can( 'create_users' ) ) {
    return true;
}
```

is trickly, but that solve what i need.

Answer (score 1):

as they said in this issue https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2252 they are not supporting this feature. I had to create custom endpoint and functionality for signups.

Answer (score 0):

Use this plug in
https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-user/

and use this end point to get nonce
http://localhost/**api/get_nonce/?controller=user&method=register**

Then let me know the result.
Thanks

Comment: this plugin uses api v1.

Answer (score 0):

Since the post is from 2018 I would like to write a short update on what possibilities you have at this point.

The plugin [JSON API User](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-user/) is still a thing and works great for that purpose.

The second solution I use for some of my customers is [WP Webhooks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-webhooks/) - It is basically an extended webhook functionality that also lets you create users on your website.

Alternatively I use Zapier in combination with some code snippets to push the data through. 
I do this by setting up a json construct and send it to my website via POST through Zapier.

Comment: Regarding the last option with Zapier - how do you actually authenticate the webhook coming from Zapier and insert the user?

Comment: With Zapier, I only use WP Webhooks to send the data to my website. This doesn't require any extra authentication, except of the webhook URL. There's a manual available here: https://wp-webhooks.com/integrations/wordpress/actions/create_user/

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in WP, you can create a nonce and then send it in the request with

wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' );

This nonce can you convert to js just using some <?php tags folded by '' and savig in a variable.

```
const nonce = '<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' ); ?>'
```

Sending in request:

```
fetch("https://your.website.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users", {
            method: "post",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'authorization' : `Basic ${Your_encoded-bit64-username-password}`, 
                'X-WP-Nonce': `${nonce}`
            },

            //make sure to serialize your JSON body
            body: JSON.stringify({your_user_data})})
           .then(res=>res.json())
           .then(res=>console.log(res))
           .catch(err=>console.log(err))
```